# Has no exported member 'AuthProvider'

Tags: ionic2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jmea.png)

I have a project in school and I'm having a hard time in fixing it.

Code:

```
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth/auth';
```

under the word AuthProvider has a red underline that says:

> [ts] Module '"c:/Users/Mikko/Ionic_Projects/myProject/FinalProject/src/providers/auth/auth"' has no exported member 'AuthProvider'.

I am not familiar with ionic2 so that's why I have no idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'export' keyword before "Class AuthProvider" in /providers/auth/auth.ts